# Integrating cocoa pods with App extension

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, ios-app-extension

I am working in a project, with cocoa pods integration.

My pod file's content as pasted below

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'HDTableDataSource'
pod 'HDCollectionDataSource'
pod 'HDAlertShortkut'
pod 'TouchXML'
pod 'ARAutocompleteTextView'
pod 'AMTagListView'

link_with 'ApplicationName', 'ExtensionName'
```

My code is in Objective C, The problem that I am currently facing is I can not import AFNetworking library in Extension's view controller.

Kindly help me to solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean you can not import library? Is it giving you an error or what?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2119

Comment: @NKorotkov, Yes When I write #import "AFNetworking.h" in my extension's view controller,  it gives error "AFNetworking.h" file not found

Comment: @HarshIT have you tried `#import <AFNetworking.h>` instead?

Comment: @NKorotkov I tried but it's not working

Comment: @HarshIT Do you got the working solution for this issue ? Even I am facing the same issue of "not able to access library files from Notification extension".